# Adding UIView Laggy on Specific iPad Models

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiview, lag

I have a pdf viewer for sheet music, which is based on PDFKit. PDFKit has an option to use an internal UIPageViewController, but it is very problematic - you cannot set the transition type, and worse than that, there is no way to check whether a page swipe succeeded or failed. You end up seeing one page, while the reported page index is another one.

Therefore I decided to create my own page flipping method. I added a UITapGestureRecognizer, and when the right or left edges are tapped, the page flips programmatically. To achieve curl animation, I add a UIView with the same image of what's underneath it, do the curl animation to the PDFView, and then remove the view. Here is part of the code:

```
// Function to flip pages with page curl
    func flipPage (direction: String) {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pdfView.bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { ctx in
            pdfView.drawHierarchy(in: pdfView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = pdfView.frame
        imageView.tag = 830
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)

        if direction == "forward" && pdfView.canGoToNextPage() {
            pdfView.goToNextPage(nil)
            let currentImageView = self.view.subviews.filter({$0.tag == 830})
            if currentImageView.count > 0 {
                UIView.transition(from: currentImageView[0],
                                  to: pdfView, duration: 0.3,
                                  options: [.transitionCurlUp, .allowUserInteraction],
                                  completion: {finished in
                                    currentImageView[0].removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        }
```

Now comes the weird part. On my own iPad Pro 12.9 inches 1st generation, this method of flipping is blazing fast. No matter the build configuration or optimization level, it simply works. If I tap in a fast succession, the pages flip as fast as I tap.

I have users with the 2nd gen iPad Pro 12.9, and they experience a terrible lag when the UIView is drawn on top of the PDFView. This also happens on all build configurations - it happened with a release build, and also happened when I installed a debug build from my computer on such a device (sadly, I could not keep the device to explore things further).

There are several other instances in the app in which I add a UIView on top  - to add a semi-transparent veil, or to capture UIGestureRecognizers. On my own device, these are all very fast. On the iPad 2nd gen, each and every one causes a lag. Incidentally, a user with a 3rd gen iPad Pro reported that the performance was very fast on his device, without any lags. On the simulator the animation is sometimes incomplete, but the response is as fast as it should be - for all iPad models.

I searched for answers, and found absolutely no references to such a weird situation. Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any quick fixes, or noticeable problems in the logic of my code?

I am afraid that if I try to draw the custom UIViews ahead of time, and only bring them to the front when needed, I'll end up with a ridiculously large amount of UIViews in the background, and simply move the delay elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research, I can provide a solution for people who face similar issues. The problem appears to be scheduling.

1. I still do not know why the 2017 models schedule their threads differently. Any ideas about why this problem reared its head in the first place is welcome. However -
2. I was not, in fact, following the best practice. Changes to the UI should always happen in the main thread, so if you encounter a lag like this, encapsulate the actual adding and removing of the UIView like this:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.view.addSubview(imageView)
       self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
   }
   ```

   My users report the problem just vanished after that.

**EDIT**

Be sure to include both adding the UIView and the animation block to the same DispatchQueue segment, otherwise they will compete for the execution slot. My final code looks like this:

```
func flipPage (direction: String) {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pdfView.bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { ctx in
            pdfView.drawHierarchy(in: self.pdfView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = pdfView.frame

        if direction == "forward" && pdfView.canGoToNextPage() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.addSubview(imageView)
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
                self.pdfView.goToNextPage(nil)
                UIView.transition(from: imageView,
                                  to: self.pdfView, duration: 0.3,
                                  options: [.transitionCurlUp, .allowUserInteraction],
                                  completion: {finished in
                                    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        }
```

P.S. If possible, avoid using drawHierarchy - it is not a very fast method.

3. In any case, if you need to code differently for specific devices, check out [DeviceKit](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit). A wonderful project, that gives you the simplest interface possible.